# Проверка на присутствие данных (name) в таблице mysql python

Tags: mysql, python, pymysql

Использую библиотеку PyMysql создаю регистрацию, хочу проверить, есть ли уже пользователь с таким именем, как это организовать?

Comment: реализуется созданием таблицы пользователей, где столбец "имя пользователя" уникальное, потом грузите туда имя и не беспокоитесь, но ожидайте исключения, решите как обработать

Comment: @EugeneDennis а через sql запросы никак?

Comment: Ну... делаете запрос записей из таблицы пользователей с этим именем, и смотрите количество найденных записей. Если ноль - новичок-с... бегите за противогазом.

Answer (score -1):

```
$res = mysql_query('select count(*) FROM table WHERE name = ""') or die();
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
if ($row[0] > 0)
{
    // Есть данные
}
else
{
    // нет данных
}
```

Или же через `exist`, что возвращает `true` при наличии.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = "")
```

Comment: Гуд. Но это не python